# Winforms - order of Load and Activated events

Tags: .net, winforms, events, load

One of our users has sent in a log for our .NET Winforms application that indicates that the `Activated` event is occurring **before** the `Load` event.  I didn't think this was possible and have coded with the assumption that `Load` would always happen before `Activated`.

Has anyone else observed `Activated` occurring before `Load`?

If so, why and is there any way to make sure it doesn't happen?

Comment: @HansaA : +1. Even in one of my existing MDI application I found this behavior. In Fresh Winform or MDI this is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks Mahin and Ash for taking the time to investigate this.  It seems like you basically can't make any assumptions about the order of these two events.  I realized that I could move the code that was in Load into a method called from the form's constructor, so I think I've solved my problem that way.  

As for the Shown event: we have a 1.1 version of the app, so we can't use that even since it was introduced in 2.0.

Comment: @HansA : The order is obviously Laod, Activated, Shown .... But as you are getting the problem in one case I am also getting the same problem.

Answer (score 21):

From [Order of Events in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms) at MSDN:

> Application Startup and Shutdown
>   Events
>
> The Form and Control classes expose a
>   set of events related to application
>   startup and shutdown. When a Windows
>   Forms application starts, the startup
>   events of the main form are raised in
>   the following order:
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.HandleCreated
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.BindingContextChanged
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.Load
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.VisibleChanged
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.Activated
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.Shown
>
> When an application closes, the
>   shutdown events of the main form are
>   raised in the following order:
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.Closing
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.FormClosing
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.Closed
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.FormClosed
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Form.Deactivate

Are you using a MessageBox in any of your startup events?  This can cause the events to appear to trigger out of order because of the way the Windows Forms Message Loop handles dialog windows.

Comment: @Ash : I have checked it in MDI form and my breakpoint is coming in sequence Activated,Load,Shown... Why so ?

Comment: @Ash : Varified with both Fresh MDI application and simple winform application. The MSDN sequence is right. But in one of my previous application where I am using MDI form it is giving me the same problem as HansaA is having in this question.

Answer (score 2):

Activated comes before Load. If you want to write some code that should be executed after Load then you can Use Shown Method.

Please find below the sequence :

> - Activated
> - Load
> - Shown

EDIT : Please check this very interesting **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397121/winforms-load-vs-shown-events/397810#397810)** on SO which explains WinForms Load vs. Shown events

> EDIT :I have Now created one default
>   Winform project with single winform.
>   Now it is giving me sequence
>
> - Load
> - Activated
> - Shown
>
> I am confused now.

Comment: @Ash : I have seen that link Ash but in my MDI form it is showing me sequence Activated, Load, Shown..

Comment: @Mahin I think then you should make it clear in your answer that this is the order you see in your MDI form, and not state it as unqualified fact.

Answer (score 2):

Even though it goes against Microsoft's documentation, this can happen sometimes when you access a loading form's public variable or function from outside the form. If necessary, you can set a flag in the shown event and use it to exit the activated handler before the form has loaded.