# Load event not firing

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I am rebuilding a project that I originally coded in SharpDevelop in Visual Studio. The relevant code worked in SharpDevelop.

The following steps should illustrate the problem:

1. Create a new project
2. Add a reference to System.Data.SQLLite (I am using the DLL for .NET 4.5)
3. In the main form, add the using statement:

   using System.Data.SQLite;
4. In the form's Load event, attach the event handler

   ```
       private void PriceType2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       MessageBox.Show("Load event hNDLER");
       SQLiteConnection con;
       //con = new SQLiteConnection();

   }
   ```

That works, but if you uncomment the next line, it doesn't.

```
        private void PriceType2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //SetDisableColors();
        //ToggleEnableOff();
        MessageBox.Show("Load event");
        SQLiteConnection con;
        con = new SQLiteConnection();

    }
```

The form opens, but the message box is not displayed. As I said, it works fine in SharpDevelop. And in case you're wondering, I am migrating the project because I need a grown up Report Viewer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Never a good idea to put a MessageBox inside a Form_Load event..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397121/load-vs-shown-events-in-windows-forms

Comment: I usually try to use Form's overrides instead of event handlers to handle the Form's own events. In this case, override the OnLoad method of your form instead. Mind you I'm not saying it's the source of your problem. Just pointing to a practice that I feel is better.

Comment: If you [break on thrown exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d14azbfh.aspx) (it only breaks on "User-Unhandled" by default) are you getting a exception thrown inside the Load event?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the reference to the assembly for .NET 4.0 (although my dev machine and all my others have 4.5) and it works. I remembered reading somewhere that there was an issue with the 4.5 DLL, but I don't know what it was.

Thanks for all the pointers.